# FlatMapIterable truncation

Tags: java, rx-java

I whish to map a list of items into observables, and then each observable item flatmap with another function to handle it to persist the results of some REST API call into database.

The API call returns correctly all the items. But, flatMapIterable doesnt pass all the items to the last flatMap.

Here is the code.

```
restApi.getContacts(user)
        .flatMapIterable(new Func1<List<Contact>, List<Contact>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Contact> call(List<Contact> contacts) {
                return contacts;
            }
        }

        .flatMap(new Func1<Contact, Observable<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Integer> call(Contact Contact) {
                return create(Contact);
            }
        })
```

I don't want to use doOnEach or doOnNext, my question is about the behavior of flatMapIterable.

Any ideas why I cannot reach all item in the last flatmap ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please make sure you have the latest RxJava: 1.0.17 or 1.1.0.

Comment: I am using 1.0.14, maybe that could be. I am going to try again.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, **just for check**, try following

instead of:

```
    .flatMapIterable(new Func1<List<Contact>, List<Contact>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Contact> call(List<Contact> contacts) {
            return contacts;
        }
    }
```

try this:

```
    .flatMap(new Func1<List<Contact>, Observable<Contact>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Contact> call(List<Contact> contacts) {
            return Observable.from(contacts);
        }
    })
```

**If it will not help**, add this code:

```
    restApi.getContacts(user)
        .doOnNext(new Action1<List<Contact>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(List<Contact> contacts) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "first doOnNext size: " + contacts.size());
            }
        })
        .flatMapIterable(new Func1<List<Contact>, List<Contact>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Contact> call(List<Contact> contacts) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "flatMapIterable size: " + contacts.size());
                return contacts;
            }
        })
        .flatMap(new Func1<Contact, Observable<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<Integer> call(Contact Contact) {
                return create(Contact);
            }
        })
        .toList()
        .doOnNext(new Action1<List<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(List<Integer> integers) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "second doOnNext size: " + contacts.size());
            }
        })
```

And print here Logcat output.

Comment: I'm going to try, Thnks!